# Python: override base class

Tags: python, inheritance

I'm looking at modifying the behavior of some 3rd party Python code. There are many classes derived from a base class and in order to easily achieve my goal, it'd be easiest just to override the base class used to derive all the other classes. Is there a simple way to do this without having to touch any of the 3rd party code? In case I've failed to clearly explain this:

```
class Base(object):
    '...'

class One(Base)
    '...'

class Two(Base)
    '...'
```

...I wold like to make modifications to `Base` *without* actually modifying the above code. Perhaps something like:

```
# ...code to modify Base somehow...

import third_party_code

# ...my own code
```

Python probably has some lovely built-in solution to this problem, but I'm not yet aware of it.

Comment: What modifications do you have in mind?

Comment: `Base` has a few methods used by its child classes that need to be modified.

Comment: It should be possible to monkey-patch in something like `Base.method = new_method` and this will be correctly resolved in the child classes' instances.

Comment: @joeln: My thinking exactly. I've just been coding up a complete demo.

Comment: @CaptainMidday: You can't just override the superclass in the subclass, then call `super().method()`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Perhaps you could monkey-patch the methods into `Base`?

```
#---- This is the third-party module ----#

class Base(object):
  def foo(self):
    print 'original foo'

class One(Base):
  def bar(self):
    self.foo()

class Two(Base):
  def bar(self):
    self.foo()

#---- This is your module ----#

# Test the original
One().bar()
Two().bar()

# Monkey-patch and test
def Base_foo(self):
  print 'monkey-patched foo'

Base.foo = Base_foo

One().bar()
Two().bar()
```

This prints out

```
original foo
original foo
monkey-patched foo
monkey-patched foo
```

Comment: Is there any way to call the original `Base.foo` inside of `Base_foo`?

Comment: @MartinvonWittich yes just keep the reference to old method, eg. `old_foo = Base.foo` and then in `Base_foo` call `old_foo(self)`. Its possible to even override magic methods like that.